# Add the name of the file as header in a text file

Tags: bash, shell

Is there a simple way to add the name of a file as a header in that file?

For example

file.txt contains:

```
blablabla
blablabla
```

Desired output:

```
file.txt
blablabla
blablabla
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(echo filename; cat filename) > filename.new
mv filename.new filename
```

Comment: to make this a one liner: ... > $$.tmp && mv $$.tmp filename

Comment: Why does a script have to be a one-liner?

Comment: @Barmar It does not literally have to be a one-liner, but there are good reasons to include the `&&` between the two statements.

Comment: @Barmar Or append a `|| exit` on line 1, for the same reason.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a one-liner which will run very quickly even with huge files and is easily used to automate this process for an entire directory.

```
x="$(basename test.txt)" && sed -i "1i$x" $x
```

You can use the filename directly (text.txt in this case) or use a variable in a loop to go through an entire directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` also,

```
sed -i "1iyourfile.txt" yourfile.txt
```

**Example:**

```
$ F="yourfile.txt"
$ sed -i "1i$F" $F
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a one-liner...

```
perl -pi -E 'say "file.txt" if $.==1' file.txt
```